# How to resize the width of the image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hello! The width of the image is same as the width of the phone screen. What's the problem and how can I reduce the size of the width? Thank you!

```
class _SignupProfileImageState extends State<SignupProfileImage> {
  bool isUploadImage = false;
  var selectedImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        top: 140,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Container(
      width: 50,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/face.jpg',
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fill              
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You set positioned right and left, so image is streetch to full width, remove it and check what happend :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, if I remove it, then I can't put the image in center :( 
I wrapped the image with Center widget, but didn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: try BoxFit.contain

Comment: I just tried it now and the image is in the squared box not circled box

Comment: put it to the row?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CircleAvatar** instead of ClipOval like below and it will be a better choice.

[CircleAvatar class you can check](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html)

```
Container(
  width: 50,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    radius: 90.0,
    child: Image.asset(
      "assets/face.jpg",
      height: 50.0,
      width: 50.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fill
    ),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
class SignupProfileImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupProfileImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignupProfileImage> createState() => _SignupProfileImageState();
}

class _SignupProfileImageState extends State<SignupProfileImage> {
  bool isUploadImage = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/face.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
}
```

You can also access the complete source code through [GitHub](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72630679).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your SizeBox with Center. It will show your Image in Center

```
return Positioned(
        top: 140,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Center( //TODO: Wrap SizedBox with Center
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                Container(
      width: 50,
      child: ClipOval(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/face.jpg',
            height: 50.0,
            width: 50.0,
            fit: BoxFit.fill              
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
```